# nav-justified not working on IE8

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-8

I have the list vertically on IE8 while on Chrome and IE11 they appear aligned next to each other as is supposed!

```
@model MyModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index2";
}

@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")

<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<title>Test</title>

<style type="text/css" media="all">
    .menu_bar > li {
        float: left;
    }
</style>

<link href="~/Content/css_index/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="~/Scripts/jQuery IE8/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

@*nav-pills nav-justified setup-tab table-bordered*@ 

<div style="top: 78px; width: 100%; overflow: auto;">
    <div class="container container-non-responsive">
        <div style="margin-bottom: 3%">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-pills nav-justified" id="myTab">
                <li class=" table-bordered active"><a data-target="#teste1" data-toggle="tab"><label style="border-bottom-style: initial">Test1</label><i class="fa"></i></a></li>
                <li class=" table-bordered"><a id="teste2" data-target="#teste2" data-toggle="tab"><label style="border-bottom-style: initial">Test2</label> <i class="fa"></i></a></li>
                <li class="table-bordered"><a id="teste3" data-target="#teste3" data-toggle="tab"><label style="border-bottom-style: initial">Test3</label><i class="fa"></i></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>                   
    </div>
</div>
```

I notice that the following classes:
nav nav-tabs nav-pills

Appear the same on IE8 and IE11 but when I add nav-justified class on the div the list shows differently on the browsers.

How can I fix this?
It's kind an emergency, I need a quick solution, thank you a lot!

Comment: I am using  `nav-justified` class, I have noticed that word wrap is the only difference from IE11 and Chrome/Firefox. In Chrome and FIrefox it is showing fine with out word wrap. Is this the problem with you also ?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, my problem is worse than that. The list appears stacked vertically instead of horizontally. Do you got this working properly in IE8 ? Thanks